# Questions on SQL Query Design based on filter expression

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some questions on sql query design for SQL Server 2008.

Lets say I have 2 tables, `UserPeriod` and `Transactions`.

The columns in `Period` are `PeriodID`, `StartDateTime`, `CloseDateTime` and `UserID`. The record in the `Period` table are as follows:

```
PeriodID    StartDateTime               CloseDateTime                 UserID
1           2013-11-13 00:00:00.000     2013-11-13 23:00:00.000       4
2           2013-11-14 00:00:00.000     2013-11-14 23:00:00.000       5
3           2013-11-14 00:00:00.000     2013-11-14 23:00:00.000       4
```

The columns in `Transactions` are `TransactionID`, `TransactionDateTime`, and `Value`. The record in the `Transactions` table are as follows:

```
TransactionID    TransactionDateTime         Value
22               2013-11-13 01:00:00.000     123
23               2013-11-14 02:00:00.000     123
```

So now I want to query for all transactions that are created in PeriodID 3. My query is something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Transactions AS t
  INNER JOIN Periods AS p
  ON (
        t.TransactionDateTime BETWEEN p.StartDateTime AND p.CloseDateTime 
    AND p.UserID = 4 
     )
WHERE p.PeriodID IN (3)
```

I could also use write my query like this to get the same result:

```
SELECT *
FROM Transactions AS t
  INNER JOIN Periods AS p
  ON t.TransactionDateTime BETWEEN p.StartDateTime AND p.CloseDateTime 
WHERE p.PeriodID IN (3) 
   AND p. UserID = 4
```

So my question is, which is the better query? This mainly concerns where I put the filter expression, `p. UserID = 4` either in the `INNER JOIN` or `WHERE` clause.

Given that I have hundreds thousands of records in each table, which query is the best, performance wise?

Secondly, Can anyone tell me whether the filter clause in `WHERE` are applied during joining the table or after all the tables are joined?

Thank you and I'm sorry for the not-so-solid example. It's the simplest example that I can think of to represent the bigger tables that I'm working on.

Comment: Use execution plan to understand which will work better for you

Comment: I guess they will be the same from execution stand point. Design? Second is better.. At least for my taste )

Comment: @evhen14 : Thank you for telling me about the execution plan.

Answer (score 0):

The execution plan produced by SQL Server Management Studio will help you to decide which one is more efficient. To my understanding they should be the same. Might be wrong, but it depends on indexes in your database.

About design. The second query is considered cleaner (and it's my personal preference) but it's up to you to decide which one you like the most. Again, I think they should be equally efficient.

PS: Can you leave a comment saying if they had the same execution plans?